# Exception thrown: 'System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException' in System.Deployment.dll

Tags: vb.net, exception

.Net 4.7.1/.2 4.8 vb.net

I left my computer on overnight running a task on analyzing some text and when I try to run any project this morning, Application.CommonAppDataPath and Application.LocalUserDataPath throw this exception, but they return the correct values.

I have many projects that use Application.CommonAppDataPath and it's happening in all of them. I created a new project and it happens there, too.

Aside from the clutter in the Immediate window, I'm concerned about what else I may find that throws the exception, so that I spend another hour tracking it down, and what else won't work at all that I haven't encountered yet.

I read every article I could find, there is stuff about ClickOnce (not sure how that is relevant) and corruption in app.config but it shouldn't be happening in new projects.

Comment: Well, it's a little hard to guess.  First thing I can think off is does the folder that Application.CommonAppDataPath resolves actually exist?  Maybe it's disk space?  And I'm assuming that you've restarted your computer since running that over night task, maybe it's messed with some environment settings.  Have you tried to repair Visual Studio?

Comment: Exists - yes, after it throws the exception it returns the correct value. I can change it any way I want from File Explorer.

Comment: Exists - yes, after it throws the exception it returns the correct value, then I can read and write. I can change it any way I want from File Explorer. I have 222 GB free. Yes, restarted. I haven't tried repairing, I supposed that's what I'll do next, I have to wait until the anxiety attack passes - began Tuesday, had nothing to do with us - meanwhile I'm hoping for a miracle answer.

Comment: Maybe try a C# project too, see if it does the same thing?  Perhaps even tag your question with Visual Studio as well

Comment: Good call, it happens in a C# project as well, but that inspired me to try .Net 5.0 and it's _not_ happening there.